# How to clear or remove items from GTK Treeview?

Tags: rust, gtk3

I want to clear treeview items(ListStore) and reassign items in a button click event.

I made the same program using with Python, Go and C#. But Rust is very hard...

Can it be done or not?

I couldn't go through the process. Until now, my program collects data when it executes (one time).

[image: By watching the image, will understand easily.]

Comment: Of course it is possible. There is the [`GtkListStoreExt::clear()`](http://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/trait.GtkListStoreExt.html#tymethod.clear) function, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Then, How can i use for them?                                                                        
        button1.connect_clicked(move |_| {
             println!("Click! Button1");
             treeview.get method ?
    });

Comment: It's hard to find example.

Comment: Thank you!, Now I can clear the treeview..

Comment: I made a few guesses at your meaning to edit the question sensibly. Please make sure I have preserved your meaning and clarify what you meant by "I couldn't go the process".

Comment: It okay now!. I solved the problem.